# Mailgun not Sending emails when variable is used as value PHP

Tags: php, email, mailgun

Whenever the "to" value is hardcoded, the email is sent. However, when the string value is replaced with a string variable the email does not get sent.

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'Eemayl Ok <mailgun@domain.net>',
    'to'      => $customerEmail,
    'to'      => Tools::safeOutput($customerEmail),
    'to'      => (string)$customerEmail,
    'to'      => $customer->email,
    'to'      => Tools::safeOutput($customer->email),
    'to'      => 'hardcoded_email@gmail.com',
    'subject' => 'We Hope You get this Email!',
    'text'    => '',
    'html'      => '<html>Contact Us Ok??</a></html>'       
));
```

The several "to"s are my attempt at variations of expressing the variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array does not accept duplicate keys. It only chooses the last value if key duplicated. According to [mailgun API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending), You should use commas to separate multiple recipients.

```
$recipients = array('client1@gmail.com', 'client2@gmail.com');
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'Eemayl Ok <mailgun@domain.net>',
    'to'      => implode(',', $recipients),
    'subject' => 'We Hope You get this Email!',
    'text'    => '',
    'html'      => '<html>Contact Us Ok??</a></html>'       
));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I figured that out a couple hours ago and was just caught up in the rush of finishing the project. (still working on it)

In a rush, however- I just made several calls with different emails *hides face*